# C++ Vector full of Vectors issue

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to write a program that will perform some graduate level numerical analysis on tri-diagonal matrices.

I'm pretty sure I have the data entry down  what I can't figure out is why the code 
`vector <vector <double>> x;` is kicking back an error of biblical proportions.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    double y;
    vector< vector< double > > x(10);

    //Stuff data packets
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cin >> y;
        x.push_back(y);
    }
    //display
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        cout << x[j] << setw(5);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << x.size(); //Making sure it's right size
    return 0;
}
```

How do I make a vector full of vectors in C++!?

Comment: Wait, do you mean the line that says vector< vector< double> > x(10); is the one not working? And if so, what error does it show?

Comment: Where is the error happening? What is the error (exact message)?

Comment: If you are getting an error and want help with it you should include the error in your question.

Comment: If you want to do something with sparce matrices, I would suggest to use a 1D vector, as anyway you need to use some kind of look up to map the indices in your matrix (in your code) to the actual matrix. Definitely you should not allocate a 30x30 matrix when only 3 diagonals are non-zero (i.e. either use a 30x3 matrix or a simple vector with 90 entries)

Comment: I'm trying to enter a matrix into c++ using vectors. I want to enter it by rows. [[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]. Trying to do this for any matrix of n rows by m columns. So I'm using a vector full of vectors to make this matrix. Then testing each row for diagonal dominance for now. Then comes the hard part. I can't seem to get the values to be entered into the vector x properly.

Answer (score 4):

The vector `x` contains elements of type `std::vector<double>`, while `y` is of type `double`. That's why you cannot `push_back` the value of `y` into `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `x` is a `vector<vector<double>>`, `x.push_back(y);` expects a `vector<double>` but `y` is just a `double`.

You either need to add `y` to a `vector<double>` and then push that into `x` or just make `x` a `vector<double>`